# Centos 6 EAP Authentication fails when wpa_supplicant is started as a service

Tags: centos, networking, services, wpa-supplicant

When I start `wpa_supplicant` as a service `sudo service start wpa_supplicant` (and the same issue if it is in a startup file), my laptop will not connect to an EAP network, with errors in `/var/log/wpa_supplicant` like:

```
1478280999.154045: OpenSSL: pending error: error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_f
ile:system lib
1478280999.154052: OpenSSL: pending error: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routi
nes:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
1478280999.154062: OpenSSL: tls_load_ca_der - Failed load CA in DER format error
:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
1478280999.154068: OpenSSL: pending error: error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL
:system lib
1478280999.154074: OpenSSL: pending error: error:0B06F002:x509 certificate routi
nes:X509_load_cert_file:system lib
1478280999.154079: TLS: Failed to set TLS connection parameters
1478280999.154085: EAP-TLS: Failed to initialize SSL.
1478280999.154091: EAP: Failed to initialize EAP method: vendor 0 method 13 (TLS
)
1478281000.477040: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
1478281002.477915: Authentication with 6c:f3:7f:af:fb:62 timed out.
1478281002.493367: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0
1478281002.993907: Failed to initiate AP scan.
1478281003.994183: Failed to initiate AP scan.
1478281004.994662: Failed to initiate AP scan.
1478281005.558072: Trying to associate with 6c:f3:7f:af:fb:72 (SSID='eduroam' fr
eq=5825 MHz)
1478281005.561055: Association request to the driver failed
1478281005.569691: Associated with 6c:f3:7f:af:fb:72
1478281005.573148: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
1478281005.845088: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=13
1478281005.845239: OpenSSL: tls_connection_ca_cert - Failed to load root certifi
cates error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
1478281005.845268: OpenSSL: pending error: error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_f
ile:system lib
1478281005.845291: OpenSSL: pending error: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routi
nes:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
1478281005.845326: OpenSSL: tls_load_ca_der - Failed load CA in DER format error
:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
1478281005.845348: OpenSSL: pending error: error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL
:system lib
1478281005.845368: OpenSSL: pending error: error:0B06F002:x509 certificate routi
nes:X509_load_cert_file:system lib
1478281005.845383: TLS: Failed to set TLS connection parameters
1478281005.845425: EAP-TLS: Failed to initialize SSL.
1478281005.845446: EAP: Failed to initialize EAP method: vendor 0 method 13 (TLS
)
1478281007.073725: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
1478281009.074324: Authentication with 6c:f3:7f:af:fb:72 timed out.
```

The following is the relevant part of my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.log`:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="eduroam"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    eap=TLS
    identity="anonymous@CERN.CH"
    ca_cert="/home/chris/cert/ca.crt"
    client_cert="/home/chris/cert/cert.pem"
    private_key="/home/chris/cert/key.pem"
    private_key_passwd="LONGPASSWORD"
    priority=10
}
```

And my `/etc/sysconfig/wpa_supplicant`:

```
# Use the flag "-i" before each of your interfaces, like so:
#  INTERFACES="-ieth1 -iwlan0"
INTERFACES="-iwlan0"

# Use the flag "-D" before each driver, like so:
#  DRIVERS="-Dwext"
DRIVERS="-Dwext"

# Other arguments
#   -u   Enable the D-Bus interface (required for use with NetworkManager)
#   -f   Log to /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log
#   -P   Write pid file to /var/run/wpa_supplicant.pid 
#        required to return proper codes by init scripts (e.g. double "start" action)
#        -B to daemonize that has to be used together with -P is already in wpa_supplicant.init.d
#   -t   include timestamp in debug messages
OTHER_ARGS="-f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.pid -t"
```

Open networks work fine, and all networks work fine if I run `wpa_supplicant` manually, as `sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -B`.

Edit: Some extra information- I have been able to access WPA2-PSK networks just fine, so it indeed appears to be specific to EAP-TLS.

Comment: The errors are a cascade of errors.  The error `tls_load_ca_der - Failed load CA in DER format error :0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied` is a failure to load the root certificate for your system's X509 certificate.  The permission denied implies that the process is not running as root/system.  Or if the current user registered the certificate as trusted, the connection process could use local user certificate and not have to load root's.  For the process to run correctly using `sudo` makes me lean toward ensuring that each user see the root certificate, or has it installed.

Comment: Another source of the cascade could be the error referring to `X509_load_cert_crl_file`.  CRL is certificate revocation list.  You do not have one in your config (sorry, I don't know how to specify one).  Can you try to disable crl checking, or at least make it optional?

Comment: @Xalorous The strange thing is that it is running as root, at least according to `ps`. So somehow it's getting permission denied as root...

Comment: @Xalorous I'll look into disabling CRL checking.

Comment: @Xalorous As far as I can tell there's not any way to disable CRL checking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem with SELinux permissions: running the command `chcon -t NetworkManager_var_run_t` on the certificates fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder `/home/chris/cert/` accessible for root ?
Also, based on [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1817462.html):

Is this folder encrypted ? can you try moving your certs somewhere else ?

Comment: All folders are accessible to root... And I already tried moving the certificates- it didn't help.